# VSTO install package How to check for prerequisites and skip them

Tags: installation, interop, assemblies, ms-office, skip

I created Setup project for my Excel add-in project according to the article:

**Deploying a Visual Studio Tools for the Office System 3.0 Solution for the 2007 Microsoft Office System Using Windows Installer**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc563937(office.12).aspx

I add prerequisites such as 2007 Interop assemblies(Office2007PIA) and when
I run my setup file it does install it.
But the problem is :
That my setup ALWAYS installs it even if my computer already has
Office2007PIA.

How can I configure my setup project that it will first check if
Office2007PIA is installed and continue the installation of my project
without installing Office2007PIA?

---

Here is the code from "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\Office2007PIA\en\package.xml":

```
<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper"
  Name="DisplayName"
  Culture="Culture"
>

  <!-- Defines a localizable string table for error messages. -->
  <Strings>
    <String Name="DisplayName">2007 Microsoft Office Primary Interop Assemblies</String>
    <String Name="Culture">en</String>
    <String Name="AdminRequired">Administrator permissions are required to install the 2007 Microsoft Office Primary Interop Assemblies. Contact your administrator.</String>
    <String Name="GeneralFailure">A failure occurred attempting to install Microsoft Office 2003 primary interop assemblies.</String>
  </Strings>
</Package>
```

And here is the code from
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\Office2007PIA\en\package.xml" "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\Office2007PIA\product.xml":

```
<Product
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper"
  ProductCode="Microsoft.Office.PIA.2007"
  >

  <RelatedProducts>
    <DependsOnProduct Code="Microsoft.Net.Framework.2.0" />
  </RelatedProducts>

  <!-- Defines the list of files to be copied on build. -->
  <PackageFiles>
    <PackageFile Name="o2007pia.msi"/>
    <PackageFile Name="ComponentCheck.exe"/>
  </PackageFiles>

  <InstallChecks>
     <ExternalCheck 
      Property="Office2007Exists" 
      PackageFile="ComponentCheck.exe" 
      Arguments="{0638C49D-BB8B-4CD1-B191-050E8F325736}"/>
  </InstallChecks>

  <!-- Defines how to run the Setup package. -->
  <Commands Reboot="Defer">

    <Command PackageFile="o2007pia.msi" 
      Arguments=""
      EstimatedInstalledBytes="30000000" 
      EstimatedInstallSeconds="60"
      >

      <InstallConditions>
        <BypassIf Property="Office2007Exists" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="0" />
        <FailIf Property="AdminUser" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="false" String="AdminRequired"/>
      </InstallConditions>

      <ExitCodes>
        <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success"/>
        <ExitCode Value="1641" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
        <ExitCode Value="3010" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
        <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" String="GeneralFailure" />
      </ExitCodes>
    </Command>
  </Commands>
</Product>
```

I suppose you mean product.xml is missing code (in node **InstallConditions**):

```
<BypassIf Property="PIAInstallAction" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="0" />
```

?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the installation is not done with administrative permissions as this is a requirement when installing assemblies to the GAC.

If you want to dig deeper you can analyze the process how the PIA installation is triggered:

Whether the Office PIA are installed is determined by a small executable included in the setup bootstrapper that checks if the PIA are actually present on disc.

The executable is named *ComponentCheck.exe* and is typically located under

*C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\Office2007PIARedist*

I suggest you run this program and check with Process Monitor whether anything fails. Based on the exit code of *ComponentCheck.exe* the installation of the PIAs is triggered or not.

This exit code condition is specified in the file *package.xml* in the same folder:

```
<InstallConditions>
 <BypassIf Property="PIAInstallAction" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="0" /> 
   <!-- Requires the user to be an admin user when installing the prerequisite --> 
   <FailIf Property="AdminUser" Compare="ValueEqualTo" 
           Value="false" String="AdminRequired" /> 
</InstallConditions>
```